# A coradius of convergence - biggest open disk contained in the image of a power series?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}\{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$ be non-constant with $f(0) = 0$, where $n \geq 1$, and let $D$ be its domain of convergence. Recall that for $n=1$ this is just some open disk $\mathbb{D}_r(0)$ with $r \in (0,\infty]$, and for $n \geq 2$ it is a logarithmically convex complete Reinhardt domain (conversely, every such domain is a domain of convergence of some power series).

> Are there known ways to calculate or (sharply) estimate a *coradius of convergence* of $f$, i.e. the biggest $R \in (0,\infty]$ such that $\mathbb{D}_R(0) \subseteq f(D)$? (This is well-defined since $f$ is open.)

I am interested in both cases $n=1$ and $n \geq 2$, but in the latter case this is perhaps too ambitious and it would be more reasonable to restrict attention to simpler domains inside $D$ (e.g. some polydisc of an appropriate radius).

Comment: Sort of related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: thanks, nice catch!